# How to allow SSH-key-based login (only) via pam rules

Tags: linux, pam, vmware, key-authentication

I am trying to allow an application to log in using only an SSH key (no password required).

The application is a backup/restore system called Veeam.  It uses vmtoolsd to log in in stead of SSH / SCP.  vmtoolsd has it's own pam.d rule file.

```
# PAM configuration for vmtoolsd

@include common-auth

account     required    pam_shells.so
@include common-account
```

I have no knowledge of pam.d rules, but I see it includes some other files, which should be default / unmodified from the OS installation default I imagine.

The error I get when trying to log in using the key only is as follow

```
Aug 18 13:46:05 server01 VGAuth[1233]: pam_unix(vmtoolsd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty= ruser= rhost=  user=root
Aug 18 13:46:07 server01 VGAuth[1233]: PAM 1 more authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty= ruser= rhost=  user=root
Aug 18 13:46:07 server01 VGAuth[1233]: vmtoolsd: Username and password mismatch for 'root'.
```

The restore succeeds if the user password is specified (in addition to the key)

Ultimately the objective is to create a new user specifically for restores, allow that user to authenticate but not get a shell, and set up key based auth only for that account.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: key-based authentication isn't controlled by PAM, sshd does it itself. Check the `AuthenticationMethods` config setting in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`. If it's unset, the default should be that just one of key-based, password or keyboard-interactive (PAM) authentication is enough. Though the server or client should also post some log messages if it tries to authenticate with a key, try something like `ssh -v -v someuser@somehost`

Comment: I wondered why I can't see anything for key based auth anywhere reading through PAM files.  Normal SSH sessions using only a key works on this server.  But for vmtoolsd it does not.  And the only hint I have is the error message.

Comment: right, if vmtoolsd implements it's own login system (using PAM or otherwise), it probably doesn't support SSH keys